# Delay (or not at all) Display of Snackbar

Tags: android, android-design-library, androiddesignsupport

A very odd issue that I'm not able to diagnose or figure out, so I'm hoping that someone else has seen this and might have a clue as to what's going on.

All Activities inherit from AppCompatActivity.

The scenario is as this:

1. Activity 1 (extends AppCompatActivity) starts Activity 2
2. Activity 2 performs some action after user input and then exits via onBackPressed
3. Activity 1 displays a Snackbar based on the action performed with Activity 2 as a means of confirmation

The problem is that the Snackbar doesn't show at all or is delayed and flickers on as it is dismissing. If I touch the screen and interact with Activity 1, the Snackbar becomes immediately visible.

I also turned on "Show layout boundaries" via the Developer Options and I can see that the Snackbar isn't actually being displayed (invisible) until I touch the screen (or until it starts to animate out).

I created a sample application and it seems to be working fine there, but no such luck in our production application. Activity 1 itself is displaying a lot of information and content in a ScrollView, but I wouldn't think that this would cause an issue, unless there are rendering passes that are happening that I can't tell and that is causing the delay in display.

Comment: What view do you pass to Snackbar as its parent?

Comment: I've tried a few things, with the same result. I've passed the rootView, the scrollView and I also experimented with adding a new coordinatingLayout and passed that view.

Comment: show some code and tell us what you tried

Comment: Colleague just suggested that I try to remove the overridePendingTransition that we are using for a custom animation and that fixed the problem....

Comment: add it then as a solution and answer your own question

Comment: Just updated my sample project to demonstrate the issue and posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've created a [project](https://github.com/akshayarora/SnackbarTest) that you can use to demonstrate this problem. I believe that this is a bug, and you can work around it by not using your own transitions. Though I also believe that not all transition animations will cause the issue. I think the hold animation in this case is the culprit.

Here is a brief outline of the issue:

1. Activity 1 and 2 both have Scroll Views with a bunch of content.
2. Activity 2 opens Activity 2 using overridePendingTransition( slide_up, slide_down), though this isn't necessary for this example.
3. Activity 3 displays content and then is closed:

   a) using overridePendingTransition( hold, slide_down ). In order to see the Snackbar in this scenario, you will need to touch the screen and interact with Activity 1.

   b) using no Transition. The Snackbar should be visible.

My solution to this issue was to remove overridePendingTransition. Please comment if you have additional ideas about this.